# Skipping strings between separator with sscanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I've got a couple of strings structed like this:

```
1|36901|O|173665.47|1996-01-02|5-LOW|Clerk#000000951|0|nstructions sleep furiously among |
```

I want to extract the fields in position 0, 1, 3, 7, in this case `1`, `36901`, `173665.47` and `0`.

I've tried

```
sscanf(line, "%d|%d|%*c|%lf|%*s|%*s|%*s|%d|%*s|", &rec.order_key, &rec.cust_key, &rec.total_price, &rec.ship_priority);
printf("%d %d %lf %d", rec.order_key, rec.cust_key, rec.total_price, rec.ship_priority);
```

and expecting to get

```
1 36901 173665.470000 0
```

instead I got

```
1 36901 173665.470000 1
```

so I guess I did something wrong with the skipping, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I figure this out: the `sscanf()` does greedy matching, so the string being skipped is too long. Using

```
sscanf(line, "%d|%d|%*c|%lf|%*[^|]|%*[^|]|%*[^|]|%d|%*[^|]|", 
      &rec.order_key, &rec.cust_key, &rec.total_price, &rec.ship_priority);
```

solved the problem.